# Can my pup actually be affected by Parvo Virus

Tags: dogs, diseases, infections

It may be that the question may have been asked multiple times, still i would like you to please analyse the question before down voting:

I have adopted 2 street dogs from an NGO in Hyderabad, India

- Male, 45 days Approx.
- Female, 2 Months Approx.

The on the second day when i brought them in, the female started showing the following symptoms:

- started rejecting food,
- vomited all over the floor and
- also had a foul smelling stool passing.
- she lost about 1.5 Kg within 1 day
- she also became very lethargic

The male on the other hand was quite fine.

The vet diagnosed her with `Parvo-virus`. For a second opinion, a second vet diagnosed her with `Hemorrhagic gastroenteritis or HGE`, citing that the stomach pain was not there. He even performed the Parvo Test using some kit which gave negative.

Optimistically we started the treatment for HGE and she had started showing improvement.

Now she is `not vomiting` at all, but her stool is now completely stinking sticky fluid. The vet is now saying it might again be `Parvo`.

Please suggest if that can be true. my vet has told me to wait for 2-3 days. but in case it is Parvo, then I need to take care of the male pup as well.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can be true for mainly two reasons:

Firstly, Canine Parvovirus (CPV) and Haemorrhagic Gastroenteritis (HGE) can look very similar. Some tests (the ones we use for example) can give false negatives, meaning that even if the test indicates that it is not CPV, it can still be CPV (happens rarely though - in my opinion, the vet should have mentioned that possibility, esp. as the first vet suspected CPV). As you noted, the prognoses differs tremendously, but the treatment and treatment goals are very similar and overlap - making it acceptable to treat for both and upon the outcome period (2-3 days vs. about a week) the suspected diagnosis can be more accurately "confirmed".

Secondly, it is possible to be infected by CPV in the animal hospital itself, or to be infected just prior to joining your family. CPV infection takes 3 - 10 days (sources for these numbers varies) to manifest and become visible to the pet owner. If your dog was for example infected with CPV on day 0 (without clinical signs) and HGE (which has a completely different cause with fast manifestation) 2-3 days later, the CPV can still become clinical 1-7 days after the HGE infection.

I would worry about the other doggie. Get him/her vaccinated ASAP!